# Need help diagnosing failing image uploads on my site

Tags: php, cakephp, upload, photos

I'm getting a lot of null'd database entries when users try to upload a photo on my site [pushroad.com](http://pushroad.com) and I haven't been able to reproduce the problem to diagnose it. If you can, try uploading a photo, and if it fails, post the details including image size, image format, etc and any other info you think will help.

Thanks!

Comment: You can easily upload photos yourself if you just need test data. Why not post your code so we can try to determine the source of the issue instead?

Comment: You do it. This is not a recruitment site!

Answer (score 0):

I would check the MIME type if this makes a difference to your app. I remember once (IIRC) IE7 sending a subtly different MIME type for some images (image/pjpeg?) that tripped up an image uploader I'd built.

In fact, see this question:

stackoverflow.com/questions/115705/why-does-ie7-specify-a-mime-type-of-image-pjpeg-rather-than-just-image-jpeg

Answer (score 0):

your directory is writable yes?

Usually, the number one cause of failed uploads is permissions issues. Check that out and make sure that you have the appropriate ones set.

Barry

Answer (score 0):

I have try to upload a photo to your website, the result url is http://pushroad.com/tags/r/73042

so there is no problem with your website